# How to access UITabBarItem from within UITests?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

Within **User Defined Runtime Attributes** I set `accessibilityIdentifier`'s value as `browseTabBarButton`.

But when I try to access this from `UITests` using:

```
app.tabBars.buttons["browseTabBarButton"]
```

`UITabBarItem` is not recognized. Why?

Comment: This seems to work on iOS 12, but not on iOS 10.

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to access the `UITabBarItem` to switch tabs, you can achieve this in a different way by accessing the buttons within the `UITabBar`:

`app.tabBars.firstMatch.buttons.element(boundBy: 0).tap()`

Answer (score -1):

Set `accessibilityLabel` instead of `accessibilityIdentifier`.

Comment: The `accessibilityLabel` is what is read out by Voice Over. It's a terrible idea setting this as an ID as the OP wants. I too would like to use the accessibilityIdentifier as I need to test in different languages so I cannot rely on the buttons label or set the `accessibilityLabel` to an ID.

Comment: Did you get this fixed >

Comment: Setting accessibility labels should be avoided because they can be localized.